# Add file at root of zip file using DotNetZip with classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, dotnetzip

I have DotNetZip installed and running fine on a Windows 2008 server.

Using a classic ASP page, I want to bundle a bunch of comma-delimited files to a user and send it over in a zip file.

The following code works fine but it stores all the path information so the files inside the zip file are located in some ridiculous directory like `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\appname\_temp\`

I'm using the following code:

```
Set objZip = CreateObject("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile")
sFileArray = Split(sFileArray, "|")
For iCount = 0 To UBound(sFileArray)
If sFileArray(iCount) <> "" Then
objZip.AddFile sFileArray(iCount)
End If
Next
objZip.Name = sFilePath & "test.zip"
objZip.Save()
objZip.Dispose()
Set objZip = Nothing
```

I see that the `AddFile` method allows you to specify where you want the added file to reside in the zip file if you add a second parameter.  According to the documentation `objZip.AddFile sFileArray(iCount), ""` should put the file in the root of the zip file.

However, when I add that parameter, I get the following error:

```
 Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'objZip.AddFile'
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of DotNetZip are you using?

Comment: 1.9, the latest.  Figured it out, sort of.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misinterperting the documentation.  If the second parameter is `null` then the directory path of the file being added is used.  If the second parameter is an empty string "" then the file is added to the root level in the zip.  A quick look into the Ioniz.zip.dll shows that the single parameter override of `AddFile` method simply calls the the double parameter override with the second parameter set to null.

Hence your add file should look like:

```
objZip.AddFile sFileArray(iCount), ""
```

to get the result you are after.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that to no avail.  I did some more research and apparently this has been an open bug with COM for a while now.  I don't think it'll ever get fixed but the work around is to call `.AddFile_2` which accepts the second parameter just fine.

Comment: Here's the link:  http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/9195?ProjectName=dotnetzip